# Jhipster: redirect to login page

Tags: spring-boot, jhipster

How to redirect to login page if a specific `exception` is raised in `JHipster`?

Comment: Have you tried returning an HTTP 401?

Answer (score 0):

There is a class in JHipster `ExceptionTranslator` which is used to handle the raised `exception`s.

You can handle whatever `exception` you want to handle in the desired way.

```
@ExceptionHandler(MyException.class)
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED)
@ResponseBody
public String processJwtException(MyException ex) {
     log.error("MyException occured : ", ex);
     return "redirect:login_url";
 }
```